# Subset trials from a list using a map function

Tags: r, mapping, subset, purrr

I am trying to create another list to include all of the trials from 2 out of the 3 variables shown in the picture.

I am trying to learn how to map this.

So far I have:

```
d2 <- map(d1 ,`[` , c("time_100L_1", "vertical_100L_1"))
```

but this only brings in the first trial. I need all 14 for time and vertical and force is in the middle of the list.

any suggestions? See picture for list [image: picture of the list]

Comment: Are `d1`, `d2` etc different objects in your environment Or they are part of the same list?

Comment: Is this what you want? `map(d1, \`[\`, c(paste0("time_100L_", 1:14), paste0("vertical_100L_", 1:14)))`

Comment: @RonakShah d2 would be a subset of d1. just the vertical and time. no force

Comment: @ekoam yes! thats perfect. Ive was thinking paste but didnt know how to write the function. Thanks! this is great

Answer (score 0):

map(d1, `[`, c(paste0("time_100L_", 1:14), paste0("vertical_100L_", 1:14)))